# Parent Sprite and it's children DisplayObjects do not fade in/out simultaneously...?

Tags: actionscript-3, animation, fadein, fadeout

I'm trying to simulate some fade in/out effects in Action Script 3 programmatically, using Timer class and controlling alpha property of the specified DisplayObject in time. In general it works and looks great. As I was expecting. But after I add some more child DisplayObjects to the parent Sprite it starts to behave weirdly. Children seem to not fade at the same rate as parent object and it visually noticeable, and ugly. There seems to be a short lag after parent already started to fade out and before children actually follow. Are there any additional measures I should take to avoid that?

I do alpha manipulation only on parent object. I thought that'd be logical...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

set the blendmode to LAYER:

```
blendMode = BlendMode.LAYER;
```

Comment: Adobe really should make this the default... A lot of people are hitting this problem when blending does not what they expect.

Comment: I think Adobe should really revise quite a lot around, including docs :(

Comment: Good to know! I always thought it was funky behaviour and had no idea there is solution to it! Not that it was a real problem to me, but still :).

Answer (score 2):

It can have simple answer. Assume your parent is gray rectangle, and the child is smaller grey rectangle. Now Flash behaves funny. It, kind of, sets the alpha of both the child (internally?) and parent. so if you have `parent_.alpha = 0.5`, imagine that the parent's RECTANGLE (the gray one) is 0.5 transparent, and THEN on TOP of it is drawn its child, which ALSO has alpha (internally, alpha property doesn't change) set to 0.5; if you place one 0.5 rectangle on top of another 0.5 rectangle, the intersecting field will be more visible than the rest.

I hope this gibberish is at least half understandable, it's kind of funky and I am not sure how to explain that well.